# css change body does not show up in html

Tags: html, css, django

With django i try to set some css code, and use it in my template.
for id/classes this seems to work but when i try to do the following, nothing happens.

in my css file

```
body{background:black;}
```

in my template

```
<body>some divs and other things</body>
```

but the background in page is still white.
When i change my template to it works:

```
<body style="background:black;">some divs and other things</body>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Other parts of the css file are normaly loaded(runserver message: "GET /static/assets/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0") 
This works like it should

```
#content{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:680px;
    height:auto;
    background:#fff;
    padding:15px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:6px solid #1C478E;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your CSS file is not being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

a) Is your CSS File available. I.e. do you have any errors while loading the CSS. Easiest to check is to call the css file manually in the browser by typing the css file url in to the browser; e.g. localhost:8000/static/main.css.

b) The file is found and contains the correct content: your HTML markup is not correct

c) The file is found and does not contain the correct content: you might have some caching, reloading issue: restart your web/development server and clear the browser cache
The File is not found: you probably have not configured your static files correctly.

Comment: Seems it is option b for me. Could you please help me where i can clear my browser cache, i am using iceweasel and cant find it at the moment - found it

Comment: Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

it seems my css file had at the top the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

this seemed to disable the normal html tag features somehow.

http://www.css-validator.org/#validate_by_input

helped me to find the problem